# I want to take the first element out of my array and give it a value based on its letter

Tags: c#

Here is the code that I currently have:

```
int firstCityMiles;

    if (words[1] == "A")
    {
        firstCityMiles = 0;
    }
    else if (words[1] == "B")
    {
        firstCityMiles = 450;
    }
```

I want to take the first element out of my array and give it a value based on its letter. However, there is probably a much better way of doing this that doesn't include many redundant if statements.

Comment: In C# array elements are numerated starting from `0`

Comment: You can use a [`Dictionary<string, int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). (See “Examples”.)

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a dictionary to store you letter to number mappings:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>{ {"A", 0}, {"B", 450}};

int firstCityMiles = dict[words[0]];
```

Don't forget that the first element in the array has the index `0`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a switch to select values:

```
int firstCityMiles;
switch (words[0]) {
  case "A": firstCityMiles = 0; break;
  case "B": firstCityMiles = 450; break;
  case "C": firstCityMiles = 600; break;
  case "D": firstCityMiles = 750; break;
  case "E": firstCityMiles = 850; break;
  default: firstCityMiles = 0; break;
}
```

You can use a series of conditional operators:

```
string first = words[0];
int firstCityMiles =
  first == "A" ? 0 :
  first == "B" ? 450 :
  first == "C" ? 600 :
  first == "D" ? 750 :
  first == "E" ? 850 :
  0;
```

(Note that the first item in the array has index 0.)